# Count value pairings from different columns in a DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["coffee","soda","coffee","water","soda","soda"],["paper","glass","glass","paper","paper","glass"], list('smlssm')]).T
df.columns = ['item','cup','size']
```

df:

```
    item    cup    size
0   coffee  paper   s
1   soda    glass   m
2   coffee  glass   l
3   water   paper   s
4   soda    paper   s
5   soda    glass   m
```

I want to transform this into a df that looks like this

```
    item    cup    size  freq
0   coffee  paper   s     1
1   coffee  paper   m     0
2   coffee  paper   l     0
3   coffee  glass   s     0
4   coffee  glass   m     0
5   coffee  glass   l     1
6   soda    paper   s     1
7   soda    paper   m     0
8   soda    paper   l     0
9   soda    glass   s     0
10  soda    glass   m     2
11  soda    glass   l     0
.    .       .      .     .
.    .       .      .     .
.    .       .      .     .
```

So for every item i want a row with the possible combinations of cup and size and an additional row with the frequency.

What is the proper way to do this using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

1. Add a frequency column to the dataframe to indicate individual rows are worth 1 each.
2. [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to get the current count in the DataFrame.
3. Create a MultiIndex from the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) values in each column.
4. Use the new `midx` to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with a `fill_value=0` so that freq gets filled with 0 when created by the new index.
5. [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to convert the index back into columns.

```
# Columns to Reindex
idx_cols = ['item', 'cup', 'size']
# Create MultIndex With Unique Values
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df[c].unique() for c in idx_cols],
    names=idx_cols
)
df = (
    df.assign(freq=1)  # Add Freq Column initialzed to 1
        .groupby(idx_cols)['freq'].sum()  # Groupby and Sum freq
        .reindex(midx, fill_value=0)  # reindex
        .reset_index()  # reset_index
)
```

`df`:

```
      item    cup size  freq
0   coffee  paper    s     1
1   coffee  paper    m     0
2   coffee  paper    l     0
3   coffee  glass    s     0
4   coffee  glass    m     0
5   coffee  glass    l     1
6     soda  paper    s     1
7     soda  paper    m     0
8     soda  paper    l     0
9     soda  glass    s     0
10    soda  glass    m     2
11    soda  glass    l     0
12   water  paper    s     1
13   water  paper    m     0
14   water  paper    l     0
15   water  glass    s     0
16   water  glass    m     0
17   water  glass    l     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
df["freq"] = 1
x = df.pivot_table(
    index="item",
    columns=["cup", "size"],
    values="freq",
    aggfunc="sum",
    fill_value=0,
)
full_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [
        x.columns.get_level_values(0).unique(),
        x.columns.get_level_values(1).unique(),
    ],
    names=x.columns.names,
)
x = x.reindex(full_cols, fill_value=0, axis=1)
print(x.stack([0, 1]).reset_index(name="freq"))
```

Prints:

```
      item    cup size  freq
0   coffee  glass    l     1
1   coffee  glass    m     0
2   coffee  glass    s     0
3   coffee  paper    l     0
4   coffee  paper    m     0
5   coffee  paper    s     1
6     soda  glass    l     0
7     soda  glass    m     2
8     soda  glass    s     0
9     soda  paper    l     0
10    soda  paper    m     0
11    soda  paper    s     1
12   water  glass    l     0
13   water  glass    m     0
14   water  glass    s     0
15   water  paper    l     0
16   water  paper    m     0
17   water  paper    s     1
```

---

Dataframe used:

```
     item    cup size
0  coffee  paper    s
1    soda  glass    m
2  coffee  glass    l
3   water  paper    s
4    soda  paper    s
5    soda  glass    m
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another approach. Check it out [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`itertools.combination`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools as it

# It's necessary a copy of your original dataframe to find the frequences, 
# because df variable will be changed in the for loop.
df_cop = df.copy() 
for index, (item, cup, size) in enumerate(it.product(df['item'].unique(), df['cup'].unique(), df['size'].unique())):
  row = list(it.combinations([item, cup, size], 3))[:3]
  df.loc[index, :'size'] = row[0]
  df.loc[index, 'freq'] = df_cop.values.tolist().count(list(row[0]))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    item    cup     size    freq
0   coffee  paper     s     1
1   coffee  paper     m     0
2   coffee  paper     l     0
3   coffee  glass     s     0
4   coffee  glass     m     0
5   coffee  glass     l     1
6   soda    paper     s     1
7   soda    paper     m     0
8   soda    paper     l     0
9   soda    glass     s     0
10  soda    glass     m     2
11  soda    glass     l     0
12  water   paper     s     1
13  water   paper     m     0
14  water   paper     l     0
15  water   glass     s     0
16  water   glass     m     0
17  water   glass     l     0
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `merge()`:

```
import itertools as it

dfa = df.groupby(['item','cup','size']).size().reset_index(name='freq')

dfb = pd.DataFrame(
    list(it.product(
        df['item'].unique(),df['cup'].unique(),df['size'].unique())),
        columns=dfa.columns[:-1])

dfa.merge(dfb, how='outer').fillna(0) \
  .sort_values(by=dfb.columns.to_list(), ascending=[True,True,False]) \
  .reset_index(drop=True).astype(int, errors='ignore')

      item    cup size  freq
0   coffee  glass    s     0
1   coffee  glass    m     0
2   coffee  glass    l     1
3   coffee  paper    s     1
4   coffee  paper    m     0
5   coffee  paper    l     0
6     soda  glass    s     0
7     soda  glass    m     2
8     soda  glass    l     0
9     soda  paper    s     1
10    soda  paper    m     0
11    soda  paper    l     0
12   water  glass    s     0
13   water  glass    m     0
14   water  glass    l     0
15   water  paper    s     1
16   water  paper    m     0
17   water  paper    l     0
```

Comment: Consider adding `reset_index(drop=True)` to the final df..

Comment: @Carmoreno Thanks - yes that is prettier.  I also modified the sort to return `size` in `s-m-l` order.